# Missing the first option when use List<T> in FormFlow,BotFramework

Tags: c#, botframework

I write a `FormFlow` demo by review the guidelines https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html, it work well.
In the demo `"Simple Sandwich Bot"` , `Sandwich.cs` , there are enum:

```
public List Toppings;

public List Sauce;

public enum ToppingOptions
{
    Avocado, BananaPeppers, Cucumbers, GreenBellPeppers, Jalapenos,
    Lettuce, Olives, Pickles, RedOnion, Spinach, Tomatoes
};

public enum SauceOptions
{
    ChipotleSouthwest, HoneyMustard, LightMayonnaise, RegularMayonnaise,
    Mustard, Oil, Pepper, Ranch, SweetOnion, Vinegar
};
```

when the code is running, and to choice `ToppingOptions` and `SauceOptions`,
the first option is missing.Is this a bug?
[a picture to show the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qli9m.jpg)

Comment: In the example they declare the list as a 'ToppingOptions' value, use 'List<ToppingOptions>' instead of List only, if it doesn't work still, try to change the first value of the enums and set it = 1, and keep the others like that

Comment: thanks for answer.You are right and the guidlines is describe:"If a field is based on an enum and it is not nullable, then the 0 value in the enum is considered to be null and you should start your enumeration at 1."

Comment: Glad it helped, i rewrite the comment as an aswer, so other people can see the correct answer if you approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in the example they declare the list as a 'ToppingOptions' value, use `List<ToppingOptions>` instead of `List` only, if it doesn't work still, try to change the first value of the enums and set it = 1, and keep the others like that

```
public enum ToppingOptions
{
    Avocado = 1, BananaPeppers, Cucumbers, GreenBellPeppers, Jalapenos,
    Lettuce, Olives, Pickles, RedOnion, Spinach, Tomatoes
};

public enum SauceOptions
{
    ChipotleSouthwest = 1, HoneyMustard, LightMayonnaise, RegularMayonnaise,
    Mustard, Oil, Pepper, Ranch, SweetOnion, Vinegar
};
```

---

As you said in the comment, *the guidlines is describe:"If a field is based on an enum and it is not nullable, then the 0 value in the enum is considered to be null and you should start your enumeration at 1."*